# Protobuf-net [ProtoAfterSerialization] Exception Case

Tags: protobuf-net

Protobuf-net allows for the following attributes:

```
[ProtoBeforeSerialization]
[ProtoAfterSerialization]
```

If there is an exception during the serialisation will the [ProtoAfterSerialization] method be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't.

I suspect a longer answer may be anticipated, but I'm not sure what else I can add...